# jquery - passing value to php

Tags: jquery

ive got 2 different php files.
first one: `A.php`, second : `B.php`

in A.php, ive got this line:

```
function altcat(id) {
            jQuery("#tvspor2").load("B.php?arupa="+id+"");
        }
```

let me explain what im doing in the A.php: 
i ve got a link in the A.php: `<a href='javascript:altcat("5")'>`
so, if a user click this link, A.php send this value to B.php?arupa=. its so simple. and B.php has this line:

```
if ($_GET["arupa"]) {
echo $_GET["arupa"];
}
```

in the A.php i ve got this line: `<div id="tvspor2"></div>` so, it shows the result.
for example: if a user clicks the link, result will show 5.

here is my question: i can show result in a div. i want to show result as a link. well, i want to use result value like that: `<a href="-i want to display altcat(id) to here.-">test link</a>`

so, i will able to create dynamic links upon the user choices. can you please kindly show me a way? ive been working on this issue for almost 3 days :( regards

Comment: do you need to just return the id number in B.php or can you return the HTML for the link?

Comment: hi, i need to use id number in the A.php. actually, <div id="tvspor2"></div> shows the id number in the A.php. however its useless for me. i need something like that in A.php: <a href=" - i need id number here -">blabla</a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use .ajax call not load, then just

```
function altcat(id){
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "B.php",
   data: "arupa=" + id,
   success: function(data){
     jQuery("#tvspor2").html(data);
   }
});
}

function okaycity(id){
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "B.php",
   data: "bule=" + id,
   success: function(data){
     jQuery("#tvspor").html(data);
   }
});
}

function thirdlink(arupa, bule){
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "B.php",
   data: "arupa=" + arupa + "&bule=" + bule,
   success: function(data){
     jQuery("#tvspor").html(data);
   }
});
}
```

and that should be it if I have understood the question right.
You need to echo HTML anchor in B.php not just number.

```
$arupa = intval($_GET["arupa"]);
if(!empty($arupa)){
    echo '<a href="'.$arupa.'">Link</a>';
}

$bule = intval($_GET["bule"]);
if(!empty($bule)){
    echo '<a href="'.$bule.'">Link</a>';
}

if(!empty($arupa) && !empty($bule)){
    echo '<a href="'.$arupa.''.$bule.'">Link</a>';
}
```

Comment: hi mate, thanks for your kindly reply. it works very well. it creates links dynamicly (it makes it in B.php), but i still cant use id number in A.php. well, actually i ve got 1 more code line function okaycity(id) {   jQuery("#tvspor").load("B.php?bule="+id+"");
  } i also get that id via different link. i want my visitors click to different 2 links. so, i wanna show third link dynamicly upon their first second choices. so, by your example, we created 1 link with 1 id, how can we create 2 links with 2 ids.

Comment: thanks. i need a link like that: <a href="$_GET["arupa"] + $_GET["bule"] ">link</a> , so 2 different ids will create 1 link href. is it possible?

Comment: Yes it is, check answer, I really don't know what are trying to do, but it should be something like this.

Comment: thanks for million times. i tested codes. first two functions works very well, but third one(function thirdlink) is not working. im going to use third one. you know, there are some chained select boxes. you select first box, than second one is dynamicly created and if you select second one third one will be created dynamicly upon your choice. well, i ve got 2 different box. user will click first link from A box, then click second link from B box, and this script should create a third link in the C box upon their choices. thats what i wanna do. anyway, thanks for your time.you helped me so mch.

Comment: function thirdlink is not working. its giving 0 value. i accepted your answer. well, ill look another way to solve. thanks