# Pass PHP value to JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I do have a file called userAuthentication.php with a function that returns a Boolean, if the authentication is successful sends "true" otherwise "false".

I also have a view called login.html, with username and password input and the corresponding submit button.

All works well, now I am wondering how could I present a message on the login.html view maybe using JS or JQuery when the function returns "false", i.e. authentication failure.

I have been going through [three PHP value pass to jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335267/three-php-value-pass-to-jquery) & [jquery - passing value to php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555670/jquery-passing-value-to-php).

I am looking for the best way to do it, so I could use the same method for any other implementation.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: This question has been asked many times before, search for ajax or see the posts below

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do this via ajax

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
username= $('#username').val();
password= $('#password').val();
$.ajax({        
    type    : 'POST',
    url : 'userAuthentication.php',
    data    : 'username='+username'&password='+password,
    success : function(data) {
        $('#report').html(data);
    }
});
 });
```

so in this scenario, the username and password values would be taken from the fields, and then passed through to userAuthentication.php, and verified. Then if the usernames and passwords were ok, the userAuthentication.php file would return a value, like "accepted", and if not it would return something like "incorrect username or password". This would then be displayed in the element id "report" in the example above.

Comment: Wow, this is great!! Source I do appreciate it :) I will go with AJAX, which sounds like a very good way to get the job done.

Comment: so make sure you have userAuthentication.php as a separate file for your ajax call. It will be just like any other POST variable, so you have if(isset($_POST['username'])) $username = $_POST['username'], to create the variables, for both username and password. Then run a sql query to see if any rows contain this username and password combination. If num_rows == 1, then you log them in, if not, then you send an error message. Whatever you echo in the userAuthentication.php file, will then be displayed in the #report element.

Answer (score 1):

use `jquery.ajax()` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ or `jquery.post()` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ or `jquery.get()` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: Thanks Andrew! I am checking the links now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is how userAuthentication.php, should look

```
if(isset($_POST['username'])) $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
if(isset($_POST['password'])) $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

$qry = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `username`='$username' AND `password`='$password'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($qry))>0 echo 'username and password accepted';
else echo 'incorrect username or password';
```